# Can mirrors on the inside of a container reflect infrared radiation thereby keeping the contents inside warmer for longer?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, reflection, infrared-radiation

So I was wondering if it was possible to prolong the "entropy" of the bottle by making sure the heat of the contents of the inside of the bottle doesn't escape by first having a secondary bottle on the inside of the existing container. Then there would be a vacuum. So would the heat stay trapped if there were mirrors on the inside of the outer container bouncing infared radiation as it gets radiated from the inner container.

Is this a means of preventing entropy increase in the universe, so could be used with dyson spheres to trap heat preventing it from escaping in the distant universe to preserve more energy? Are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: Ever used an emergency blanket? That aluminized Mylar works quite well to reflect IR.

Comment: Do you consider constructing a Dyson sphere an issue?

Comment: Dewar/vacuum flasks have their surfaces silvered for exactly this reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of a Dyson sphere is to collect the low-entropy light from the star, use its energy, and then radiate the energy at higher entropy. Trapping the energy would not be productive: the temperature would rapidly rise until your sphere melted.

Answer (score -1):

Imaging no energy escapes the Dyson sphere, it would get hotter and hotter on the inside surface. Second would you like to live on a mirror?